# Prevent developers from creating new git remote branches

Tags: git, git-branch

In a centralized workflow, is there any way (with local or server configuration) to prevent developers from creating new remote branches in git?

We are happy creating local branches but sometimes this local `spikes` or `test-feature` branches are going to remote by mistake.

Any way to avoid this without going to a more restricted workflow?

Comment: You could make developers use forks of the repo and submit pull requests from their respective fork

Comment: Thanks @ErikSvedin but I would not like to change our flow as I said at start of my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `.git/hooks/pre-receive`

```
#!/bin/sh
rc=0
while read old new refname; do
        if [[ $refname == refs/heads/* && $old != *[^0]* ]]; then
                rc=1
                echo "Refusing to create new branch $refname"
        fi
done
exit $rc
```

Comment: Can someone explain what the regex * [^0] * means?

Comment: @Setafire It's not a regex, it's a shell pattern.  It's "anything that has a non-"0" in it somewhere", so not matching that means `$old` is all "0"s  That's easier to verify than `0000000000000000000000000000000000000000`, in awk I do `z8=00000000` and compare against `z8 z8 z8 z8 z8`, in python it's just `'0'*40`.

Comment: Interesting! I have done bash shell scripting, but never come across this. Can you point some reference? So, what if I have to specify a certain match for the old name starting with? Let's say, I want to check old name starts with 'F'. I am having a hard time making this work through git.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a hook in your server, so the pushes will be scanned and any new branch rejected.

Place this hook within the "hooks" folder in your shared repository (the script shall be named "update")

```
#!/bin/env python
"""
Server side hook that checks if a branch being pushed already exists and rejects
the commit if not

It prevents the creation of new branches in a shared repository
"""

import sys
import os

branch_id = sys.argv[1]

# Tag pushes are not blocked
if branch_id.startswith('refs/tags'):
    exit(0)
elif not os.path.exists(branch_id):
    print("You are not allowed to create new branches")
    exit(1)
```

Check [this link](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-An-Example-Git-Enforced-Policy#_an_example_git_enforced_policy) for more inf about git-enforced policy

**Edit:**
Based on the feedback from jthill, there's an alternative implementation that, instead of search for the branch ref file, actively elaborates the list of existing branches *(it may be improved by calling a plumbing command instead of call to "git branch" as I'm doing here)*

```
#!/bin/env python

import sys
import os
from subprocess import check_output


def tags():
    return [i.lstrip(' *') for i in check_output(["git", "branch"]).split('\n') if i!='']


def main():
    branch_id = sys.argv[1]

    # Only ref/heads are being processed
    if branch_id.startswith('refs/heads/'):
        if not branch_id.lstrip('refs/heads/') in tags():
            exit(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: That will fail on any repository with packed refs.

Comment: Usually, `git pack-refs` is used to pack tags (which are not being checked by the hook) but not branches. Nevertheless, I'll add an alternative implementation for that situation were the repository has been packed by calling the `git pack-refs` with the `--all` argument.

Answer (score 0):

What git server do you use ?

In `gitolite`, for example, you can set ACL based on the branch/tag name and the user "login" (see the doc [here](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/conf.html#rules))